# Section of tensor product of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I consider a locally free coherent sheaf $E$ on $X$ and similarly $F$ on $Y$. Now suppose that I have a global section $s$ of $E \boxtimes F$. Why does this section induce a map $H^0(X,E)^\vee \to H^0(Y,F)$?